# How to make a deprecated PKToolPicker method work for iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift

I am initialising my `PKToolPicker` on `viewWillAppear` and have the following code:

```
private func initialiseToolPicker() {
    guard let window = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window! else {
        return
    }
    
    guard let toolPicker = PKToolPicker.shared(for: window) else {
        return
    }

    toolPicker.addObserver(canvasView)
    toolPicker.addObserver(self)
    toolPicker.setVisible(true, forFirstResponder: canvasView)

    updateLayout(for: toolPicker)

    canvasView.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

This works on all devices except iOS 14. What happens is that the first time the view appears it never reaches the becomeFirstResponder() line. Then if I close and reopen the view, it works.

I can't tell which line it fails at but I know that the line `let toolPicker = PKToolPicker.shared(for: window)` is deprecated in favour of `let toolPicker = PKToolPicker()`. However, my computer is too outdated to be able to run Xcode 12, so I can't build and submit that! Does anyone have a hack that would make this work (until I can get a better computer)?

Comment: try to use this window : UIApplication.shared.windows.first

Comment: please ensure the line is executing in ios14 > `guard let toolPicker = PKToolPicker.shared(for: window) else {
        return
    }`